# Elasticsearch: Unable to restart the service because no space left on device

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running a single node ES 2.X on a centOS aws instance

The ES service refuses to start because of - `No space left on device` error and unless the service starts, I can't run a `snapshot & delete` script that I have written.

Is there anyway I can restart the service?
It would be helpful if you could give me pointers to monitor the size growth so that I don't end up in this situation again.

P.S: All the help online suggests deleting files to restart, but I am not sure what files to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete all of your elasticsearch data in `/var/lib/elasticsearch`. 
You can also create one more elasticsearch node and add it to your cluster, part of data will migrate to this node.
I never worked with `aws` so I can't help you with aws-specific monitoring solutions. We use `Zabbix` on our cluster for monitoring

Comment: Thank you. I shall try adding a node to the cluster.
When I look at `/var/lib/elasticsearch`, I can see a folder for every index that has been ever created, could i just copy this to another ES location and restart ES and make it work like - `backup-delete-restore`?

Comment: I'm not sure. You can surely try, but for this you'll need to move all your data to another server anyway. You can just let elasticsearch do it's work and relocate data itself. You should probably also tweak configs to speed relocation up. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shards-allocation.html

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to check is location of your files below:

**path.data:** /home/elasticsearch 
**path.logs:** /home/logs/elasticsearch

It should resolve the problem

But, if you don't have enough space even to restart the elastic after making changes you should consider removing all unwanted files.

Solution for Centos 6 is given below:

1. yum -y install yum-utils
2. find /var -name "*.log" ( ( -size +50M
   -mtime +7 ) -o -mtime +30 ) -exec truncate {} --size 0 \;
3. yum clean all
4. rm -rf /var/cache/yum
5. rm -rf /var/tmp/yum-*
6. package-cleanup --quiet --leaves --exclude-bin package-cleanup
   --quiet --leaves --exclude-bin | xargs yum remove -y
7. rm -rf /root/.wp-cli/cache/*
8. rm -rf /home/*/.wp-cli/cache/*
9. rm -rf /root/.wp-cli/cache/*
10. rm -rf /home/*/.wp-cli/cache/*
11. package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=2
12. rm -rf /root/.composer/cache
13. rm -rf /home/*/.composer/cache
14. find -regex ".*/core.[0-9]+$" -delete
15. rm -rf /root/.npm /home/*/.npm /root/.node-gyp /home/*/.node-gyp /tmp/npm-*

Try restarting elastic search now.